Minimum Hilbert-Schmidt matrix norm with fixed diagonal entries and rank
I want to verify whether the following holds:
If $A=(a_{ij})\in M_d(\mathbb{C})$ satisfies $a_{ii}=1$ for $i=1,\ldots, d$ and $\mathrm{rank}(A) = k$, then $\displaystyle \|A\|_2^2=\sum_{i,j=1}^d |a_{ij}|^2\geq k-1+(d-k+1)^2$.
The equality indeed holds when $a_{ij}=0$ for all $1\leq i\neq j\leq k-1$ and $a_{ij}=1$ otherwise, so the point is whether this is optimal for the Hilbert-Schmidt norm.
I could only check for the case $d=3$ with a brutal force and the cases $k=1$ or $k=d$, but I don't have any clever idea for the general cases.
